# GRPC Service with Generic proto request data in GoLang

Tags: go, grpc, proto

I have 3 protos as follow:

1 - record.proto

```
message Record {
    int64 primaryKey = 1;     

    int64 createdAt = 2;
    int64 updatedAt = 3;
}
```

2 - user.proto

```
import "record.proto";
message User {
    Record record = 31;
    string name = 32;
    string email = 33;
    string password = 34;
}
```

3 - permissions.proto

```
import "record.proto";
    message Permissions{
        Record record = 31;
        string permission1= 32;
        string permission2= 33;
    }
```

Question1:
Is there a way to implement a grpc server and client in golang that takes specifically Record as request but entertains both later types. i.e User and Permissions.
Something like:

```
service DatabaseService {
    rpc Create(Record) returns (Response);
}
```

So that I can send grpc client request as both follow:

```
Create(User) returns (Response);
Create(Permissions) returns (Response);
```

Comment: This is like asking "Can the go function `func foo(int)` entertain a string and a boolean"; the answer is "not as-is" but you could, instead, change the definition to take a `struct` (a new `message` in proto terms) that incorporates all possible inputs (perhaps using a `oneof` as suggested in the existing answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `oneof` which allows the client to send either `User` or `Permissions`.
Refer https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#oneof

```
message Request {
    oneof request {
        User user = 1;
        Permissions permissions = 2;
    }
}
```

So client can fill any of them in the request.

```
service DatabaseService {
    rpc Create(Request) returns (Response);
}
```